# Constructing dependent random variables that are conditionally independent

Tags: probability, independence

I'm trying to understand better the difference between independence and conditional independence.

If I have three independent random variables, X, Y and Z, how could I construct two random variables A and B using X, Y and Z, such as A and B are not independent, but are conditionally independent given Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $A=X+Z$ and $B=Y+Z$?

($A$ and $B$ are only dependent if $Z$ is not almost surely constant; if it is, there is no solution.)